# In Pokemon, is the 'Attack' action the last action that is performed on your turn?

Tags: pokemon

Is the 'Attack' action the last action you take during your turn or can you take other actions after this is done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically yes, attacking is the last action you take prior to ending your turn. See the [TCG Rulebook, page 9](https://assets.pokemon.com//assets/cms2/pdf/trading-card-game/rulebook/swsh3_rulebook_en.pdf).

> 3. Attack. Then, end your turn.

Some turns you may take other actions to end your turn and not attack. But there is no second main phase like in Magic. Once you declare an attack there is no more playing cards unless the attack requires it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I'm use to playing Magic and having that second main phase.

Comment: Indeed - the reverse here, I rarely remember to save mana for second main. But the reason is that there are no instants - and so no reason to save resources. It is a simpler turn, in some ways.

Comment: Yeah it is, but a bit confusing in some other ways haha. Only started playing it as my step-son was really keen on the game. He kept stating that you could take other actions after attacking, hence the question.

Comment: Yep, it’s very common for kids that learn on the playground to learn a lot of rules differently than the official rules!  Consider trying out the online game (PTCGO) to get an idea of the complete official rules - it’s free to play.

Comment: YGO also has phases after the attack phase, that allow players to respond to any trap cards or flip effects that their opponent activates as a direct result of an attack. This mechanic isn't in Pokemon, so extra phases aren't often necessary or even desirable.